# Merge and interpolate dataframes with pandas

Tags: pandas, merge

I am using **LASIO** library to import and merge several LAS files into one dataframe, using "DEPT" column as an index. Here is a graphical explanation of what I need:

[scheme with explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaiXZ.png)

This part of the code is looks like:

```
def selectFiles():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    root.withdraw()
    return filename

las_files_list = selectFiles()
df_list = []

#Clean dataframe
wdf = pd.DataFrame()
wdf = wdf[0:0] 

for f in las_files_list:
    las = lasio.read(f)
    lasdf = las.df()
    well_name = str(las.well.WELL.value)
    lasdf['well'] = las.well.WELL.value
    lasdf['DEPT'] = lasdf.index
    df_list.append(lasdf)

for idx,ldf in enumerate(df_list):
    if idx == 0:
        wdf = lasdf
    if idx > 0:
        wdf = pd.merge(wdf,ldf, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_'+str(idx), '_'+str(idx)))
```

But I've got a problem if there is a mismatch in Indices.
Total amount of Index values is very high (10k-20k length), and small gaps can be easily interpolated without loosing data reliability.
Could you please suggest me how to do this?

I've tried to load and merge all dataframes using first column (DEPT) as index (basically, it is the position of data on Y axis). But there are common situations when data from files with different index values (in decimals) is not merging.

Comment: In my opinion, I would attempt to `union` all the dataframe indexes into one index, then use that one index to `resample` all the dataframe, `join` all the dataframes together on index and then `interpolate` values for each column.

Comment: According to your diagram, you don't care about the index when you do the interpolation. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can concat and then interpolate:

```
pd.concat(df_list, axis=1).interpolate()

# to properly interpolate based on index values
pd.concat(df_list, axis=1).interpolate(method='index')
```